# Algorithm for windowed online covariance

Tags: algorithms, math

I'm trying to adapt an algorithm to calculate covariance to work over a rolling window on the data. Wikipedia has [an algorithm for online covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Covariance):

```
def online_covariance(data1, data2):
    mean1 = mean2 = 0
    M12 = 0
    for x, y in zip(data1, data2):
        n += 1
        delta1 = (x - mean1) / n
        mean1 += delta1
        delta2 = (y - mean2) / n
        mean2 += delta2
        M12 += (n - 1) * delta1 * delta2 - M12 / n
    return n / (n - 1) * M12
```

But I need this to work over an arbitrarily sized rolling window. I've already adapted a different algorithm on that Wikipedia page for variance to work on a rolling window, but I'm getting stuck doing it for covariance.

The below pseudo-code is what I have so far. Assume the `window` function returns an enumerable over a structure that contains the elements entering and leaving the window (`Entered` and `Exited`, respectively).

```
def online_covariance(data1, data2, windowSize):
    mean1 = mean2 = 0
    M12 = 0
    i = 0
    covars = []
    for x, y in zip(window(data1, windowSize), window(data2, windowSize)):

        if(n < windowSize)
            n += 1
        delta1 = (i < windowSize ? x.Entered - mean1 : x.Entered - x.Exited) / n
        mean1 += delta1
        delta2 = (i < windowSize ? y.Entered - mean2 : y.Entered - y.Exited) / n
        mean2 += delta2

        // Up to this point I can verify the algorithm is correct- 
        // it keeps the correct means for each data set
        // This next line is where I'm stuck- 
        // it needs to be modified to remove the value that 
        // just left the window
        M12 += (n - 1) * delta1 * delta2 - M12 / n

        covars.Add(n / (n - 1) * M12)
        i++
    return covars
```

Comment: Have you tried just passing the data for your rolling window into the original function?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I need to calculate the results of consecutive rolling windows over a large date range. Calling the function over and over again would be very slow- thus wanting to do this with an online algorithm.

Comment: Well, couldn't you pass your data range by reference, and the start and end points, to your function?  You could then loop over that, outside of the function.  Calling the function repeatedly is only going to be slower if you're copying the data in your window and passing the copy to the function.

Comment: I'm saying that you're having difficulty because your function is doing too much.  Make a function that computes one window given the start and end locations within your large data set, and then make another function that loops over those windows.

Comment: Copying is not the problem. The behavior you're describing is O(n^2). For each data point I'd need to loop over the entire window that preceded it. I need O(n) (single pass).

Comment: But don't you still have to loop over the subset anyway?  Or is it a matter of keeping a running total?  I haven't looked at the problem in detail, but couldn't you simply subtract the value that just left the window, and add the value that just entered the window?

Comment: No, this function will return a list the same size as the input data that contains the covariance computed over the window. It will do this in a single pass. I need help figuring out the math changes to make it work. I should make the return type more in my pseudo code.

Comment: For those looking for a more explicit algorithm (and derivation), see [stdlib](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib), which includes an implementation for computing a moving (aka sliding window) [online covariance](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib/blob/4c7910500f132993fa396b666a0d11a2f4d81214/lib/node_modules/%40stdlib/stats/incr/mcovariance/lib/main.js) along with documentation showing how to derive the update [formula](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib/blob/4c7910500f132993fa396b666a0d11a2f4d81214/lib/node_modules/%40stdlib/stats/incr/mcovariance/lib/main.js).

Answer (score 2):

**To begin with**

Just think about how you'd compute Var(X) online (where X is an unending stream of numbers).

What you'd do here is keep track of two quantities:

1. Sum of all X values (i.e. sum(x1, x2, x3, ....))
2. Sum of all X^2 values (i.e. sum(x1^2, x2^2, x3^2, ...))

Then when you need to compute the variance after 1,000th x values all you do is return

```
Var(X) = SumOfSquares/n - (Sum/n)^2
```

(this formula is given because Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2)

**To compute Cov online**

Keep track of these quantities (As mentioned above this means subtracting off quantities that are no longer in your window)

1. Sum of all X values in your window (i.e. sum(x1, x2, x3, ....))
2. Sum of all Y values in your window (i.e. sum(x1, x2, x3, ....))
3. Sum of all X*Y values in your window (i..e sum(x1*y1, x2*y2, x3*y3))

All that is left is a little algebra...which I'll leave to you.

**From a coder's point of view**

I suggest writing a function like this:

```
double covar(cumulativeSumOfXs, cumulativeSumOfYs, cumulativeSumofXYs){
    //only simple algebra is necessary if these are your inputs
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so for sample covariance the formula I have is 1 / (n - 1) * [Sxy - (1 / n) * Sx * Sy]. My concern though is that Wikipedia warns this is subject to [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation).

Comment: @MgSam -- Regarding catastrophic cancellation: many mathematical computations can "go wrong".  The mere fact that a computation can go wrong doesn't necessarily mean you shouldn't use the "vulnerable" algorithm by default.  For example, think of gaussian elimination (a simple method for solving linear systems of equations -- Linear Algebra 101 stuff).  This extremely simple approach that works well much of the time.  However, this simple approach works poorly when a matrix condition number is large.  Should we throw-out a simple, easily understood algorithm just because bad inputs can exist?

Answer (score 0):

For two dimensional data, start with these variables initialized to zero, and given `(x, y)` is your new data point, do

```
t0 += 1
t1x += x
t1y += y
t2xx += x * x
t2xy += x * y
t2yy += y * y
```

Decrement these variables accordingly when points leave your window.

When you need to obtain covariance matrix for accumulated data, do

```
cxx = (t2xx - t1x * t1x / t0) / d
cxy = (t2xy - t1x * t1y / t0) / d
cyy = (t2yy - t1y * t1y / t0) / d

yield [
  [cxx, cxy],
  [cxy, cyy],
]
```

where `d` either equals to `t0 - 1` for sample covariance (e.g. using Bessel's correction), or `t0` for population covariance.